# Spectrum of laplacian in a parallelogram

Tags: geometry, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Is the spectrum of the laplacian on an arbitrary parallelogram with dirichlet boundary conditions known?

Comment: What are the boundary conditions?  Dirichlet?  Periodic?  Neumann?

Comment: Right, dirichlet, thanks for reminding me.

Comment: Have you played around with changing coordinates and separating variables?

Comment: I mean that if you have, those would be good things to include in your question - by showing what you've tried and where you got stuck, people will be more likely to help you.

Comment: You could find some of the eigenfunctions for the special case where the parallelogram decomposes into two equilateral triangles. Even for this case, this wouldn't be all of the eigenfunctions, and for the more general parallelogram, it wouldn't help at all.